# how to show device camera's data on a CCScene when using cocos2d-x on android

Tags: camera, cocos2d-x

In an android game, I want to start device's camera and let player see the camera input inside a CCScene. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for the same thing. I haven't figure it out yet but come across the following:

http://syswerke.com/projects/blog/opencv-camera-capture-in-cocos2d-x-applications/

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#opencviosvideoprocessing (iOS)
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller-and-cocos2d-sample-code/#post-34228 (iOS)

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/11524 (suggesting to save to file/buffer and pass to native code)

I've seen example on iOS that works (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM9EIzB5I-8).

I'll update more if/once I figure it out